# Enable submit button if the user enters correct string

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jquery autocomplete and getting the autocomplete suggestions. I want to enable the submit button if the user enters the correct short name(i.e. options['value']) name in the input.
The HTML input(index.php):

```
<input class="form-control typeahead" id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete" placeholder="COMPANY NAME" type="text" />
<div id="res"></div>
<button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-success" id="success" disabled>SUBMIT</button>
```

And logic to enable submit button(index.php):

```
$("#res").click(function(){
    $("#success").prop("disabled", false);
});

$("#autocomplete").keyup(function(){
    if (!($('.autocomplete-suggestions').is(':visible')) && $('#autocomplete').val() != '' && options.hasOwnProperty($(this).val())) {
        $("#success").prop("disabled", false);
    }else {
        $("#success").prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

JQuery autocomplete function(search.js):

```
var options;
$(function(){
  options = [{ value: "WIPRO", data: "Wipro ltd" },{ value: "TCS", data: "Tata consultancy serv lt" },{ value: "INFY", data: "Infosys limited" }];
  $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
    lookup: options,
    appendTo: '#res',
  });
});
```

The error I'm getting in the console is: ReferenceError: options is not defined. I'm new to this, can anyone please help to solve this?

**Note:** The search.js file is included in index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a modified version of JosephC's answer with a strict check on the input. `isValidUserInput` checks strictly if the user input is one of the pre existing companies in the options array. Even if the user selects a value from dropdown and changes his input at that point as well this will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $autoComplete = $("#autocomplete"),
        $success = $("#success");
    function isValidUserInput(input){
        return app.options.some(function(option){
            return input.toLowerCase() === option.label.toLowerCase();
        });
    }
    $autoComplete.keyup(function(){
        if(isValidUserInput($(this).val())) {
            $success.prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
            $success.prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
    $autoComplete.autocomplete({
        source: app.options,
        appendTo: '#res',
        select: function(){
            $success.removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
 });
```

and the html unchanged from your question.

```
<input class="form-control typeahead" id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete" placeholder="COMPANY NAME" type="text" />
<div id="res"></div>
<button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-success" id="success" disabled>SUBMIT</button>
```

not related to this question but since you mentioned a scope issue in the comments, try defining a namespace like `App` as following.

```
var App = {};
$('document').ready(function(){
    App.options = [{ label: "WIPRO", data: "Wipro ltd" },{ label: "TCS", data: "Tata consultancy serv lt" },{ label: "INFY", data: "Infosys limited" }];
    // rest of your code...
});
```

You can access options from a different file using `App.options`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added this code in index.php, but still getting the error: ReferenceError: options is not defined. I think I cannot access the options variable(which is declared in search.js) from here. can you tell me how can I access that?

Comment: @SoumyajitGorai I guess you have defined options variable in search.js file inside another `$(document).ready` function. In this case you can't access options inside the `$(document).ready` callback function in a different file. Updated my answer with the scope issue fix.

Comment: Thanks @sbr. I can access it now but the button doesn't get enabled on correct input. My current code looks like:
`$('#autocomplete').keyup(function() {
if( isValidUserInput($('#autocomplete').val()) ){
console.log('matched');
$('#success').removeAttr('disabled');
}else{
$('#success').prop('disabled', true);
}
});`


`isValidUserInput` function works like charm but the button still remains disabled.

Comment: hmm. working for me. here is my codepen link. https://codepen.io/cplog/pen/WZJBMG

Comment: Checked your codepen link @sbr. It's not working... the button gets enabled only when you click on the suggestions. As soon as I finish typing "WIPRO" or any other correct label the submit button should be enabled, that's not happening. The button remains disabled.

Comment: @SoumyajitGorai sorry about that. I updated the answer and codepen as well. not using `forEach` anymore and using Array.some to check if user input is equal to at least one of the companies listed in options. I also made it case insensitive so that user can either enter `tcs` or `TCS` and still get the submit button enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value selected by the user in the autocomplete from the select event, and enable the submit button in that function, also the source must be mentioned, refer docs here -- http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ :

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#autocomplete").keyup(function(){
        if($(this).val()=== '') {
          $("#success").attr("disabled", 'disabled');
        }
    });

    var options;
   
    options = [{ label: "WIPRO", data: "Wipro ltd" },{ label: "TCS", data: "Tata consultancy serv lt" },{ label: "INFY", data: "Infosys limited" }];
    $('#autocomplete').autocomplete({
        source: options,
        appendTo: '#res',
        select: function(){
            $("#success").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });
    
  
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link href = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css"
         rel = "stylesheet">
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
  </head>
<body>
  <input class="form-control typeahead" id="autocomplete" name="autocomplete" placeholder="COMPANY NAME" type="text" />
<div id="res"></div>
<button type="button" class="form-control btn btn-success" id="success" disabled>SUBMIT</button>
</body>
</html>
```